# Error in installing ROS indego Ubuntu 14.04 in Mac OS

Tags: 14.04

i tried to download ROS indego more than 3 times and i always receive the same error in the end of the installation : i followed the instructions here http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

my laptop is 14.04 LTS

N: Ignoring file 'ros-latest.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

N: Ignoring file 'ros-latest.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

what is the solution ??

Comment: That's not what the site install instructions tell you do add to your sources list. http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu

Comment: i want ROS indego not jade , are they the same ??

Comment: Plz help , i dont know what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

That's not what the site install instructions tell you do add to your sources list. http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

According to the site install instructions what you need to add is this:

> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release
>   -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

Set up your keys

> ```
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116
> ```

For the following and detailed steps visit the install instructions site again.

Comment: i followed the steps exactly before and i still have the same problem , btw i dont recive any message once i run the first code !

Comment: i followed the steps step by step: untill i reached the desktop full installation , it was installed but in the end some errors appears